# Why is the IP address of my remote ice candidate the same as my (Janus) WebRTC signaling server?

Tags: webrtc, stun, janus

I am trying to make video calls with WebRTC and Janus. I am able to make calls using the video call demo page supplied by Janus as well as through an iOS app - this is all working perfectly fine.

However, when inspecting the network flow through both wireshark and `chrome://webrtc-internals/` the connection does not seem to be directly to the public IP of the other device. Instead the data is directed to my Janus signaling server. It seems that the IP of the `remoteIceCandidate` is equal to the IP of my signaling server - shouldn't this should be equal to the public IP of device 2?

Is this correct behavior or not? If so, why is the remote IP not equal to the public IP of device 2? If not, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is correct behavior and a mistake on my part. The [Janus video call plugin documentation](https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/docs/videocall.html) says the following:

> The idea is to provide a similar service as the well known AppRTC demo (https://apprtc.appspot.com), **but with the media flowing through a server** rather than being peer-to-peer.

Therefore, the media data is supposed to go to the server instead of over a peer-to-peer connection.